# Using refs with react-redux 6.0.0 and decorators

Tags: redux, react-redux, decorator

I have the following component:

```js
export default
@connect(null, dispatch => ({ dispatch }))
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {

}
```

And I have a component wrapping it:

```js
export default class MyWrapper extends React.PureComponent {
  comp = React.createRef();

  render() { 
    return <MyComponent ref={this.comp}/>
  }
}
```

How do I access `MyComponent` using refs?

I tried `{withRef: true}`, then tried `{forwardRef: true}` and got all sorts of errors.

Comment: It was using connect as a decorator that burned me. I has a cryptic error message when trying to use `{forwardRef: true}`. Turns out the actual error was because I was using `connect` as a decorator rather than as a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the React-Redux `connect` docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#forwardref-boolean), you need to pass `{forwardRef : true}` as an option to `connect`:

```js
connect(mapState, mapDispatch, mergeProps, {forwardRef : true}
```

This is the same whether you're using `connect` as a separate function, or as a decorator.

On which note: for reference, we do *not* recommend using `connect` as a decorator.

Comment: I get the following error: `Expected a Constructor`

Comment: I can tell you what the React-Redux `connect` API requires, but I have no idea what your build setup is like.  The decorators spec and plugins are still not stable, which is the biggest reason why we recommend against using `connect` as a decorator.

Comment: It doesn't work with decorator really. The other way works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `"react-redux": "7.0.0"`. The `connect` function has been implemented as a functional react component, so `@decorators` is not working anymore.